# I have an error of Undefined index: file in php

Tags: php, image, pdo, upload

Hi I am having an  Undefined index: file error here it says `$fileName`, `$fileTmpName`, `$fileSize`, `$fileError`, `$fleType`  are the problems.

```
if(isset($_POST['pic_submit'])) //if UPLOAD is clicked
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $fileName= $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

            var_dump($fileName);
        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $target_dir = "/images/";
        $target_file = $target_dir.$fileName;


        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'gif');
        //if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed))
        //{

        if(isset($fileName))
        {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$imageFileType;
            $fileDestination = '../images/'.$fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
        }
```

}

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/1937483

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure everything is set inside of your main `if` condition. The [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) has an arity of variadic length, so you can ensure that all your conditions are set before you enter your loop.

Just doing:

```
if(isset($_POST['pic_submit'], $_FILES['file'])) //if UPLOAD is clicked
```

should cut it.